# fetch json file on react component render,using async await

Tags: reactjs, json, async-await, promise, fetch

I need to fetch a json file containing people names and use that data to populate the page.
The fetch should happen when the component loads and while is doing it the page should render a 'loading...' text.I managed to do the getPeople() function using .then,is there a way to it with async await ?

code:

```
import React from 'react'
import {useState,useEffect} from 'react'
import People from './People'
const component = () =>{
  const getPeople = () =>{
    fetch('file.json'
    ,{
      headers : { 
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
      }
    }
    )
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((myJson) => {
      const males_names = myJson?.males?.map(({name,last_name}) => name + " "+ last_name);
      const females_names = myJson?.females?.map(({name,last_name}) => name + " "+ last_name);
      setLoading(false);
      setmales(males_names);
      setFemales(females_names);
    })
  }
  const [pageIsLoading,setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [males,setMales] = useState([]);
  const [females,setFemales] = useState([]);
  useEffect(()=>getPeople(),[]);
  return (
      <div>
          {pageIsLoading ? 'Loading...' : <People people={{males,females}} };
      </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: "*The fetch should happen when the component loads*" - you mean when the component is mounted, or when the module code is loaded?

Comment: What's the point? Using async await is useful when you need to do things in order. Here you're just fetching one json file. By the way, you should try to use axios instead of fetch, much easier to use and only one then

Comment: "*is there a way to do it with async await?*" - sure, just write `getPeople` as an `async` function; the call is exactly the same. Have you tried it? Where are you struggling?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
async function getPeople() {
   let response = await fetch("...")
   let data = await response.json()
    ...assign variables...
}
```

I dont really see a reason to it that way tho, since it is the same as with fetch. If you like the asthetic of await more you can combine the two.

```
async function getPeople() {
   let data = await fetch("...").fetch(response => response.json())
   ...etc...
}
```

This may look better to you since your code isnt wrapped in a .then() bracket then.

Comment: Your second snippet does not work

Comment: Thanks, should work now